# Number of connected sets on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{A}_n$ denote the family of all connected sets over $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $n=1$ we have that the cardinality of $\mathcal{A}_1$ is the cardinality of the continuum. But if $n>1$  I've only shown that $\mathcal{A}_2$ is at least the cardinality of the continuum. If $n> 1$ does the cardinality of $\mathcal{A}_n$ is $2^{\mathbb{c}}$? or does it exist an $n$ such that $|\mathcal{A}_n| = 2^{\mathbb{c}}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right for $n=1$, and the same is true for path connected in place of connected.  For $n>1$, the cardinality of the connected spaces, and even the path connected spaces, is always $2^c$ because one can easily see that $\leq$ holds.  For $\geq$ one needs to construct a $2^c $ family of path connected subsets.  Consider the set of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form

$\{(x, y)|x=0\}\cup\bigcup_{r \in S} \{(x, y)|y=r\}$ for any subset $S$ of the reals.